# Inherit dependencies among projects

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, windows-phone-8.1

Due to an architecture requirement, I would have to have **all the 3rd party dependencies centralized in a single project.** Then, the remaining projects in the solution would have this project referenced as a dependency to inheriting all of these dependencies in order to avoid having them duplicated along the solution.

I'm wondering if that's possible even if I have to make some tricky adjustments to make it work.
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you reference a project, you are not necessarily referencing it's dependencies.

So, say I have Project A that references 3rdPartyLib.dll.  when I reference ProjectA.dll, I'm not referencing 3rdPartyLib.dll.

One way to do it would be to write all of the logic that uses 3rdPartylib.dll in Project A, and essentially use it as an abstraction layer.  Then reference projectA.dll and call that logic, and the calling assembly would have no knowledge of 3rdPartyLib.dll

Comment: Thanks much for your quick response @MavisBeacon! I've tried implementing one thing (that actually doesn't have to do with the question I've asked) using the schema you've suggested but it hasn't worked as I expected. What I've done is to creating a kind of wrapper that implements some functionalities of the 3rdPartyLib.dll. When I call this wrapper in another project, I get a deployment error asking for the dll referenced in the current project.

Comment: On the other side, rather than implementing the logic of a 3rdPartyLib, what I would like to have is a kind of dependencies repository wrapped in a single project. This is an approach that is attainable in other technologies architecture such as Android or iOS, and I was wondering if that was possible in terms of Microsoft technologies.